# How to get products info using direct sql query in magento 2?

Tags: mysql, magento2

I want to get product info using direct sql query,

```
sku price  status.  special_price. quantity
1.   10.   enabled.   5             10
2.   20.   disabled.  10            20
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is creating a php file in root folder:

And paste the following code in the php file:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$row_id_sql = 'SELECT row_id FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE entity_id = "1000"';
$row_id_sql_fetch = $connection->fetchAll($row_id_sql);
```

You can replace the query with yours.

Comment: please provide me sql query

Comment: what table and what data you want?

Comment: I want product info which includes sku, price, special price , quantity, status